# SQL - WHERE utilizando 2 condições e o AND como condicional - Resposta não é o resultado esperado

Tags: sql, where, count

Boa tarde, a dúvida é bem básica.

Estou fazendo a contagem dos itens de uma tabela única  para duas "classes" específicas (M e N), dentro de uma mesma coluna (duas possíveis saídas é o que eu estou chamando de "classe"). Quando uso o comando WHERE com apenas uma classe o resultado apresentado é correto:

**Contar quantas ocorrências do tipo M**

```
SELECT COUNT(Name)
 
FROM Data$

WHERE Policy_Group_Name = 'M'
```

ou

**Contar quantas ocorrências do tipo N**

```
SELECT COUNT(Name)
 
FROM Data$

WHERE Policy_Group_Name = 'N'
```

Porém quando uso o condicional AND e as duas condições recebo 'O' ou 'NULL' como resultados:

**Contar quantas ocorrências do tipo M & N**

```
SELECT COUNT(Name)
 
FROM Data$

WHERE Policy_Group_Name = 'M' AND Policy_Group_Name = 'N'
```

Não sei onde estou errando, sei que deve ser algo simples, mas não estou conseguindo enxergar, se alguém puder ajudar agradeço.

Abraço.
Bia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Os operadores lógicos tem por função relacionar proposições lógicas. Os principais operadores lógicos são:

```
AND
Será verdade se e somente se as duas expressões relacionais forem verdadeiras

OR
Será verdade quando ao menos uma das expressões relacionadas for verdade

NOT
Será verdade somente quando a expressão associada a ele for falsa
```

Ao relacionar as expressões `Policy_Group_Name = 'M'` e `Policy_Group_Name = 'N'` com o operador AND, sua consulta passa a buscar um campo da coluna onde o valor de `Policy_Group_Name` seja 'M' e 'N' simultaneamente. Sugiro que utilize a seguinte expressão:

```
Policy_Group_Name = 'M' OR Policy_Group_Name = 'N'
```

Dessa forma você terá retorno nessa consulta daqueles campos onde Policy_Group_Name for igual a 'M' ou 'N'.

Comment: Me caiu essa ficha almoçando, mas vocês foram mais rápidos......rs. Sorry, fiquei com o somar na cabeça, aí passei para o código.......Aí deu ruim.... Valeu **@dududornelees**, **@Gabriel Gomes Nicolim** e **@Ricardo Pontual**.

Answer (score 2):

Você está usando a condição `AND`. Ou seja, você está procurando por um resultado onde o `Policy_Group_Name` seja igual a "M" e também seja igual a "N".

A instrução correta neste caso seria a utilização da condição `OR`, ficando assim:

```
WHERE Policy_Group_Name = 'M' OR Policy_Group_Name = 'N'
```

Desde modo, você estará procurando por resultados onde `Policy_Group_Name` seja "M" ou "N". Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Ajudou sim, obrigada.

Comment: também WHERE Policy_Group_Name IN ('M'  'N')